# Почему нужно использовать dirname(__FILE__) в php

Tags: php, include

Во многих проектах видел подключение стороннего файла в таком виде:

```
<?php
  include( dirname(__FILE__) . '/file.php' );
?>
```

По идее, этот код выполняет те же действия:

```
<?php
  include( 'file.php' );
?>
```

Так в чем же разница и почему программисты используют именно первый вариант?

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628443/

Comment: @GlebKemarsky не знаю английский, хочу получить русскую документацию

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php

> Файлы включаются, исходя из пути указанного файла, или, **если путь не указан, используется путь, указанный в директиве [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)**. Если файл не найден в `include_path`, `include` попытается проверить директорию, в которой находится текущий включающий скрипт и текущую рабочую директорию перед тем, как выдать ошибку.

Поэтому вижу две причины указывать абсолютный путь:

1. Избежать неожиданностей, вызванных вмешательством директивы `include_path`.
2. Ускорить работу: сразу пойти по абсолютному пути, а не перебирать директории, которые могут подразумеваться.

С версии 5.3 вместо `dirname(__FILE__)` можно использовать `__DIR__`. [В этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749423/6263942) пишут, что это может работать ещё быстрее, потому что `__DIR__` определяется на стадии компиляции, а `dirname(__FILE__)` означает вызов функции и поэтому происходит во время исполнения.